# ¿Puedo añadir una página HTML en la carpeta public de Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

quería cargar una página "xxx.html" en carpeta public/ de Laravel 5 o una subcarpeta de ésta, para mostrar un prototipo.

La idea sería poder cargar una página con una URL como: https://midomio.es/xxx.html o https://midominio.es/public/xxx.html.

¿Se puede hacer? ¿cómo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay nada (dentro de Laravel) que impida poner o mostrar una página HTML estática en la carpeta pública de Laravel, la carpeta pública de Laravel no es más que (normalmente) el directorio raíz desde donde se sirven los archivos.

Laravel tiene su/sus puntos de entrada allí, en el caso del web, utiliza index.php, pero si yo agrego un archivo prueba.html y escribo en mi navegador: http://mipagina.com/prueba.html, funcionará como en cualquier otro servidor con configuración típica.

Lo único que impediría que se puedan leer páginas html sería alguna configuración específica del servidor que permita solo acceder por index.php (por ejemplo).

Comment: Vale lo estaba probando con subdirectorios en remoto. Si dejo el fichero "prueba.html" en el directorio public si que funciona, tanto en local como en remoto. Pero si dentro de `public`, uso un subdirectorio ya no. Es decir, que para el fichero `public/demos/pruebas.html´ uso la URL: https://midominio.es/demos/prueba.html ya entraría en juego el sistema de rutas y el mi caso me sale la página 404, aunque solo en remoto.

Comment: Realmente depende de la configuración del servidor, debería funcionar perfectamente en los subdirectorios también, sin ningún inconveniente, a menos que tengas una ruta definida en laravel con `demos/xxxx`, yo solo utilizo nginx y me funciona en cualquier proyecto en producción sin problema, de hecho tenemos algunos archivos así en subdirectorios.